# String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long on Bit Column

Tags: php, mysql

I just recently added a bit column and for some reason, I cannot edit its value. Everything else is fine. I look for the error online and some people recommended disabling the strict mode, so I did. Thank you for looking at my question.

I tried disabling the strict mode using `SET sql_mode = '';`, but it still doesn't work.

SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_users;

```
| tbl_users | CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` (
  `user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_role_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `admin_approved` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

edit.php

```
<?php
//DB Connection
include 'conn.php';

if ($_POST['action'] == 'edit') {
    $data1 = [
        ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':admin_approved' => $_POST['admin_approved'],
        ':user_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
    ];

    $query1 = "
 UPDATE tbl_users
 SET first_name = :first_name,
 last_name = :last_name,
 email = :email,
 admin_approved = :admin_approved
 WHERE tbl_users.user_id = :user_id
 ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query1);
    $statement->execute($data1);
    //$statement->close();
    //echo json_encode($_POST);

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    if ($result) {
        echo "Successfully Edited";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}



if ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {
    $data2 = [
      ':user_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
  ];

    $query2 =
     "
DELETE FROM tbl_users
WHERE user_id = :user_id
";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query2);
    $statement->execute($data2);
    //$statement->close();
    //echo json_encode($_POST);

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    if ($result) {
        echo "Successfully Deleetd";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

//echo json_encode($_POST);
?>

<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$post_data) {
        echo "You posted:" . $key . " = " . $post_data . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Error msg:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'admin_approved' at row 1 in /var/www/html/wordpress/multi_users/edit.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wordpress/multi_users/edit.php(23): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/var/www/html/wordpress/multi_users/edit.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` what does `admin_approved` contain?

Comment: @aynber it contains: ```array(6) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(2) "45"
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(4) "Jose"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(5) "Scott"
  ["email"]=>
  string(16) "casada@gmail.com"
  ["admin_approved"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["action"]=>
  string(4) "edit"
}```

Comment: Could you try if `intval($_POST['admin_approved'])` works?

Comment: @digijay it didn't work

Comment: After looking a bit more I also needed to change the global strict mode. I used ```SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode= ' ';``` to do it and it allowed me to change it to true, but no backwards.

Comment: Switching off error checking is not a solution

Comment: Your column `admin_approved` is not a boolean, it is of type `bit`. You can't store a string or a number in there.

Comment: @Dharman I agree, do you see where I can do changes in the code?

Comment: Change `bit(1)` to `int` or `tinyint`

Comment: Thank you @Dharman, that worked!!

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: @tadman OP is using PDO.

Comment: @Dharman They're using both inexplicably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data type `BIT` only accepts binary values. You specified the length to be 1 bit long but you try to input a string of value `'1'` which in binary is `00110001` and it obviously overflows.

The recommended practice for storing booleans in database is to use nullable DateTime data type. e.g.

```
`admin_approved` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
```

Then if the value is populated you know the boolean state is on, and if the value is NULL the boolean state is off. Additionally you know when the flag was switched on.

You could also use `tinyint` and store 1 or 0. However, from experience I can say it is not very useful.